# Single Thread CPU Performance with PHP

Tags: php, central-processing-unit, lamp, cpu-usage

I have a lamp web server running a website that is getting very feature bloated. I have a few pages that are taking 2-3 seconds of CPU time to render the PHP. Most other pages a processed in about .2 seconds.

I have optimized the DB calls and am running SSD drives but the application is about as optimized as I can get it at this point.

I was thinking about cheating a little bit by upgrading the processors. The problem is that the 2016 processors are only about 30% faster in single thread performance than my 2011 processors.

Am I correct that a processor with the same single thread speed isn't going to be any faster for an individual page load? I understand that it will be able to handle concurrent page loads better but that's not the problem at the moment.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: `but the application is about as optimized as I can get it at this point.` I don't believe this - you should use a profiler to create a callgraph of the slow pages. Take a look at xhprof for example (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xhprof.php). In the moment, you seem to have no idea, where your actual problem lies.

Comment: You forgot to show CPU and disk usage statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think faster processors make more than 10 - 20% real world performance.

My suggestions:

- Optimisation of the code probably makes most sense. This may need a
  developer, who can reduce database calls, reduce general work done,
  or simply optimise it.
- Putting in a page cache, unless the page is
  customised for each user. Nginx is great for this, and it can either
  sit in front of or replace your current web server. Caching is probably the fastest, best solution unless each page is customised for each user. [Even caching for 30 seconds can help](https://www.nginx.com/blog/benefits-of-microcaching-nginx/).
- Put in a CDN, which won't help page generation time, but may help load other
  resources and make it feel faster. Setting your caching heads is
  essential for this. CloudFlare for example has a free tier.
- Try HHVM instead of plain PHP - it can be significantly faster than PHP5. It's written by facebook and not every PHP app works on it - but Wordpress and the couple I've tried do.